# Python: Modifying an XML File

Tags: python, xml, lxml

I'm stuck, I've written a code that looks for specific index in xml file. But when find that Index won't create me a new xml file with just that Index in and constant parameters. 
it returns an error:

```
...rba_u_xml.py", line 29, in <module>
ObjectDictionary.remove(Variable)
File "C:\Python27\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 337, in remove
self._children.remove(element)
ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list
```

this is my code:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('master.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

s = input('Insert a number of index and add quotes(") befor and after: ')
i = int(s, 16)

for MagicNumber in root.findall('MagicNumber'):   #constant parameters
    print MagicNumber.tag,':', MagicNumber.text
    print('\n')
for FileInfo in root.find('FileInfo'):
    print FileInfo.tag,':', FileInfo.text
print''
for DeviceInfo in root.find('DeviceInfo'):
    print DeviceInfo.tag,':', DeviceInfo.text
print''
for DummyUsage in root.find('DummyUsage'):
    print DummyUsage.tag,':', DummyUsage.text
print''
for ObjectDictionary in root.find('ObjectDictionary'):
    name=ObjectDictionary.get('name')
    print ObjectDictionary.tag,':', ObjectDictionary.text, name
    print''                                                       #constant parameters

    for Variable in ObjectDictionary.iter('Variable'):          #searching for Variables in index
        if Variable.find('./Index').text == str(i):
            print 'Variable name: ', Variable.attrib['name']
        elif Variable.find('./Index').text != str(i):
            ObjectDictionary.remove(Variable)

    for Record in ObjectDictionary.iter('Record'):             #searching for Records in index
        if Record.find('./Index').text == str(i):
            print 'Record name: ', Record.attrib['name']
        elif Record.find('./Index').text != str(i):
            ObjectDictionary.remove(Record)

    for Array in ObjectDictionary.iter('Array'):               #searching for Arrays in index
        if Array.find('./Index').text == str(i):
            print 'Array name: ', Array.attrib['name']
        elif Array.find('./Index').text != str(i):
            ObjectDictionary.remove(Array)


tree.write('output.xml')            #That would be amended to create a new xml file
```

Thanks for your help!
I hope you understand(in the other case ask) because I use google translator a lot  :)

Comment: Well, Variable is not in ObjectDictionary.

Comment: where else could be? i tried with root but still the same error...

Comment: @user3540670 Side note: Read PEP 008 http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/ and try following naming rules proposed there. Your naming conventions are a bit odd for Python code and make understanding it more difficult.

Comment: I don't think that's the main reason. have anybody any other solution?

Comment: I solved it(on half)! the solution I past in ansewr

Answer (score 0):

I solved it! :D Insted of xml.etree.ElementTree modul I use xml module and insted of ObjectDictionary.remove(Variable) I use Variable.clear()

I use lxml module

```
from lxml import etree as ET
tree = ET.parse('master.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
```

-

```
s = input('Insert a number of index and add quotes(") befor and after: ')
i = int(s, 16)

for MagicNumber in root.findall('MagicNumber'):   #constant parameters
    print MagicNumber.tag,':', MagicNumber.text
    print('\n')
for FileInfo in root.find('FileInfo'):
    print FileInfo.tag,':', FileInfo.text
print''
for DeviceInfo in root.find('DeviceInfo'):
    print DeviceInfo.tag,':', DeviceInfo.text
print''
for DummyUsage in root.find('DummyUsage'):
    print DummyUsage.tag,':', DummyUsage.text
print''
for ObjectDictionary in root.find('ObjectDictionary'):
    name=ObjectDictionary.get('name')
    print ObjectDictionary.tag,':', ObjectDictionary.text, name
    print''                                                       #constant parameters

    for Variable in ObjectDictionary.iter('Variable'):          #searching for Variables in index
        if Variable.find('./Index').text == str(i):
            print 'Variable name: ', Variable.attrib['name']
        elif Variable.find('./Index').text != str(i):
            Variable.clear()                         #insted of ObjectDictionary.remove(Variable)

    for Record in ObjectDictionary.iter('Record'):             #searching for Records in index
        if Record.find('./Index').text == str(i):
            print 'Record name: ', Record.attrib['name']
        elif Record.find('./Index').text != str(i):
            Record.clear()                             #insted of ObjectDictionary.remove(Record)

    for Array in ObjectDictionary.iter('Array'):               #searching for Arrays in index
        if Array.find('./Index').text == str(i):
            print 'Array name: ', Array.attrib['name']
        elif Array.find('./Index').text != str(i):
            Array.clear()                               #insted of ObjectDictionary.remove(Array)


tree.write('output.xml')            #create a new xml file
```

In new xml file is now  left just tags of variables,records and arrays.

`<Group name="OptionalObjects">
            <Array/><Array/><Variable/><Variable/><Variable/><Record/><Record/><Record/><Record/><Record/><Record/><Record/><Record/></Group>`

Have anybody any idea how to solved out this (I hope) last problem?